# Why I am having error Call to undefined function get_header()?

Tags: errors, headers

I am using twenty eleven for my theme and I create a PHP page under it named results.php in the results.php here's my code:

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

From my index.php:

```
get_header(); ?>
<a href="wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/result.php">Main</a>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: How do you call the custom PHP file? Directly? As a template?

Answer (score 1):

You get `undefined function` because you are pointing to the result.php directly. That way WordPress just doesn't load.

If you need to include result.php in a specific place use [get_template_part](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) or even better [locate_template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template)

Answer (score -1):

There is no opening `<?php` tag in your second (index.php) block of code.

It should look like,

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<a href="wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/result.php">Main</a>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Ammend that <strike>and try again</strike>

#### Edit:

I didn't read that clearly the first time around but you need to link to your Result page like this,

```
<a href="<?php get_the_permalink();?>/result/">Main</a>
```

At the top of `result.php`, change it to read:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Result Template
*/
get_header(); 
?>

//do your results stuff here... or get regular page loop.

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

In your dashboard, go to **Pages**, **Add New** and enter a *Title* named **Result**.

Then from the right hand side **Page Attributes** meta box, select your **Result Template** from the drop down menu and then Publish the page.

When you visit `http://www.yoursite.com/result/` your page and its content will show correctly using the `result.php` page template created and assigned.